# cv2 won't import after successfully installing it

Tags: python, opencv

I have a single `.py` file with nothing in it except `import cv2`. When I run: `pip install opencv-python`, it tells me that requirements are already satisfied but when I run it, it tells me there is "No module named cv2"

I'm using VSCode with Python 3.9.1

How could I solve this issue??

Comment: Does your python and pip have same path? If you're using linux or MacOS, you can check it with `which` command.

Comment: @Y.P I'm on Windows. How could I check for that?

Comment: Is it possible that you have more than one version of Python in your system? Did you use Anaconda to install the module but did not set PATH Variable with VSCode?

It is quite likely your module might be installed locally instead of globally.

Try changing the Python interpreter in VSCode if you have more than one versions.

Or you could check first on your python interpreter:

`import cv2`

`cv2. __version__`

Comment: I changed the interpreter from 3.9.1 to 3.7.9 and it works fine now. What could have been the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using python 3 you should use

```
pip3 install package <name>
```

or pip install package as python 2X

you can try some different method here : https://java2blog.com/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-cv2-python/

Answer (score 0):

Your pip command may be connected to the python 3.7 because it works well when you change python interpreter.

1. Change your python interpreter to you want to use (3.9)
2. Check the interpreter is set correctly.

```sh
python -V
```

3. Install OpenCV

```
python -m pip install opencv-python
```